# Adjusting Height of a Listbox in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to Adjust the Height of a Listbox to increase or decrease Dynamically based on the Items binded to it in windows phone 7 silverlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the Height of the listbox to `Auto`